# Is this the right way to start more secure session in PHP?

Tags: php, security

I'm new to web development and even newer to sessions. I use the following code to start a session in one of my PHP files and include it everywhere else:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private_no_expire');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha256');

session_start();
```

Is this the right way to start a session so as to reduce the number of possible session attacks (which I'm not all familiar with, but I know they exist)?

EDIT: Is adding `session_regenerate_id()` right after `session_start()` above regenerating the session ID too frequently if this file is included in every page? Should I just include `session_regenerate_id(true)` for the login process?

Comment: you can  set those options in `php.ini` or in `.htaccess`

Comment: @LeaTano Are there benefits to doing that? I'm hesitant in messing around with those files, specifically php.ini, because there seems to be a lot of stuff on there that I don't really understand...

Comment: the benefit will be... you don't have to set them on each page. Always make a copy of the `php.ini` and then you can change these values. With `.htaccess` is much easier, since if something stop working you can just delete it

Comment: @LeaTano How do you make changes with `.htaccess` and where is that file usually stored? I'm using XAMPP on Windows right now.

Comment: you have to create a file named `.htaccess` on documentroot (I believe, by default in xampp is `c:\xampp\htdocs`

Comment: @LeaTano And I'm assuming I can set things on there the same way they're set in the `php.ini` from a syntax perspective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71929/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-user4181107).

Comment: `ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 0);` - why no HTTPS? startssl.com and cloudflare.com both give free TLS certificates

Comment: @Scott I haven't started learning about HTTPS yet, not sure how to implement it yet, but I do plan on implementing it before production. If you know of a good source to learn it, do share. Also, do I have all my bases covered with everything else?

Comment: I did a presentation on it at Bsides Orlando last year but sadly it did not get recorded. There are plenty of tutorials on the Internet, however.

Answer (score 1):

How to set session options:

**php.ini Solution**

Change directly the values

**.htaccess Solution**

Create a file named `.htaccess` on documentroot (I believe, by default in xampp is`c:\xampp\htdocs`

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value session.cookie_lifetime 0
  php_value session.use_cookies 1
  php_value session.use_only_cookies 1
  php_value session.use_strict_mode 1
  php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
  php_value session.cookie_secure 0
  php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
  php_value session.cache_limiter 'private_no_expire'
  php_value session.hash_function 'sha256'
</IfModule>
```

**PHP Solution** (you need to setup this options on each file)

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private_no_expire');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha256');
```

Comment: What does the `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` tag mean?

Comment: but i can't find the values in `php.ini`??

Comment: also, wouldn't `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0)` immediately delete all cookies?

Comment: These values should be in php.ini. Search each one. The file path is: c:\xampp\php\php.ini